# How can I find duplicate key violations in a different collation?

Tags: mysql, collation

I have a MySQL table that has the collation for one of its varchar columns in the primary key set to `utf8_general_ci`. I want to change the collation to `utf8_unicode_ci` so it stops treating *"gmail.com"* and *"gmàil.com"* like they're the same item. I tried running this:

```
alter table my_table change character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The alter fails with a duplicate key violation on one of the items.

> **Error** 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry `2013-07-15-119-comcast.net` for key `PRIMARY`

I tried selecting the items out of the table that have `date` equal to 2013-07-15 and `source_id` equal to 119, but eyeballing the results I don't see two entries for *"comcast.net"* that might be causing the problem.

Can I construct a query into this table to determine which two rows are different under `utf8_general_ci` but the same under `utf8_unicode_ci`?

Comment: best solution - convert the table to the same collation with all other, many benefits and prevent other collisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query like this did the trick:

```
select date, thing_id, email_domain collate utf8_unicode_ci
from my_table
where date = '2013-07-15'
and thing_id = 119
and email_domain collate utf8_unicode_ci = 'comcast.net';
```